# Copy multiple images from folder to html site

Tags: html

This is probably a silly question but I'm new at this!

I have a html gallery that i want to upload images to but i have around 400 of them, I'm manually changing the name i.e. bob to the next one i.e ted, all of the images are named as i would like them, is there a quick method to take all of the file names and replace the html code with the image name?

Currently I'm searching for the name in notepad ++ and replacing it with the next for each image

Any help appreciated thanks!

Example code below so i will replace bob with ted, frank etc.

```
                <div class="ct-gallery col-sm-6 col-md-2">
                    <a class="ct-js" href="./assets/images/content/bob.jpg" title="bob">
                        <figure class="ct-hover">
                            <img src="./assets/images/content/bob.jpg"  alt="">
                            <figcaption>
                                <h2>bob</h2>
                            </figcaption>
                        </figure>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

Comment: Not with HTML only ... ;)

Comment: W3S says: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp

Comment: ***NEVER*** use w3schools as a reference! The information on that site is not reliable!